# Adding characters to a string in forloop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having a bit of a problem with my code.
I wanna go through a string with a for loop and replace '*' with "**" and any character that appears mutiple times right after each other with "*nc*", in which n is the number of appearances and c is the character.

I'm going through the String with a for loop but I end up with only one letter instead of a complete String.
If I were to enter "ff", it will return *2f* correctly but If I add anything else It just overwrites it again.

For example, if I were to enter "abcdefg" I would get "g" instead of "abcdefg".

"input" is a JTextField.

```
String inputs = input.getText();
String result = new String();

int counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length(); i++){
    if(inputs.charAt(i) == '*')result += "**";

    else if(i < inputs.length()-1){
        if(inputs.charAt(i) != inputs.charAt(i+1) && counter == 0){
          result = result +  inputs.charAt(i);
        }

        else if(counter != 1 && inputs.charAt(i) != inputs.charAt(i+1)){
            result = (String)(result + "*" + counter + inputs.charAt(i) + "*");
        }

        else if(inputs.charAt(i) == inputs.charAt(i+1)){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    else if(counter != 1){
        result = (String)( result + "*" + counter + inputs.charAt(i) + "*");
        counter = 1;
    }
    else result = result + inputs.charAt(i);
```

//Edit It's working now. I fixed the 'counter == 0' but that didn't really make any difference since I added the char at the end anyway.
The other thing I changed is adding a 'continue' after every statement.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length(); i++){
    if(i < inputs.length()-1){
        if(counter != 1 && inputs.charAt(i) != inputs.charAt(i+1)){
            result = (String)(result + "*" + counter + inputs.charAt(i) + "*");
            counter = 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if(inputs.charAt(i) == inputs.charAt(i+1)){
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else if(counter != 1){
        result = (String)(result + "*" + counter + inputs.charAt(i) + "*");
        counter = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if(inputs.charAt(i) == '*'){
        result += "**";
        continue;
    }
    else{result = result + inputs.charAt(i);}
}
```

Comment: For one, I would recommend using StringBuilder instead of String if you are building up a String.

Comment: The continues aren't needed because it will automatically loop once it hits the ending bracket.

Also you didn't change  `int counter = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You set `counter` to 1 before the loop starts, but in the loop you check if it's equal to 0.  It's never going to be 0, because the only thing you ever do to `counter` is increment it or set it to 1.  This is almost certainly where your bug is.